# Center Image in div

Tags: css, html, center

I'm trying to center an image in a div I created. What am I missing here? I tried putting a style on the image, but that didn't work either.

http://jsfiddle.net/huskydawgs/8zs29/

```
  <div class="wrapper-data">
<div class="data_row">
  <div class="data_cell1_100">
        <img  width="450" height="509" src="http://oedblog.electricstudiolt.netdna-cdn.com/wpcms/wp-content/uploads/apple-e1382039006457.jpg" /></div>   
  </div>
```

```
.wrapper-data {
position:relative;
width:100%;
border: none;
margin: 30px 0 0 0;
overflow: hidden;
```

}

```
.data_row {
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    white-space:nowrap;
    display:table;
}

.data_cell1_100 {
    width:100%;
    display:table-cell;
    white-space:normal;
}

.data_cell1_100 img {
    display:block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Center vertically, horizontally, or both?

Comment: Do you really need the `data_row` and `data_cell1_100` divs?

Answer (score 4):

`.data_row` also needs `width:100%;`

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/8zs29/1/

**Reason:** Short and friendly, percentage width is relative to the parent element, you need to "pass it along" to your destination element. So if you intend to have the 100% width of the outer most element, in your case all of the width of the body with the 100% of the viewport, then all of the preceding elements should have the 100% width.

Answer (score 1):

add `width:100%;` to div with the class `.data_row`